# jQuery 1.7 .on() and Dynamic Form Catching

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms, jquery-1.7

I'm having a problem with jQuery 1.7's latest `on()` function. I'm moving all of my existing `live()` calls to the new `on()` function.

In the past I used `live()` whenever I created a new element or appended some markup from AJAX.

With jQuery 1.7 If I append form markup returned via AJAX and try to use `e.preventDefault` or `return false` to stop it from submitting (to validate it for example) — the form is submitted as normal.

```
$(document).on('submit', 'form', function(e) {
    alert('You tried to submit the form');
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: not completely positive here, but maybe try binding directly to the form?

Comment: @kand that would defeat the purpose.

Comment: Could you create a fiddle that causes this issue?  It seems to be working http://jsfiddle.net/markcoleman/E6e79/1/.

Comment: Is this browser related? Does it work in one browser but not another?

Comment: It might be too late to prevent the default action at this stage (though it should not imo). Try `document.body` as selector.

Comment: @KevinB why would that defeat the purpose? $('form').on('submit', function(e){...}); would do essentially the same thing. It is more specific and might require some refactoring, but it might solve the problem.

Comment: @kand Because his forms are dynamic. In order to bind directly the form would have to be static or he would have to bind in the success callback of the ajax calls that generate the forms.

Comment: I've tried to upload an example but of course my simplified example works perfectly as it should with the above code. I'll update when I discover the problem.

Comment: @KevinB Well clearly it would require refactoring, I suggested it as a possible solution. Anyways, my suggestion is an answer that's posted below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been confirmed as a jQuery bug in 1.7.1, to be fixed in 1.7.2: http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/11145

My original code is correct (for dynamic DOM elements). Adam Rackis' code is correct for existing DOM elements.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is perfectly valid.

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/xzeVX/)

If you post some more code we might be able to take a look and see if you have some other problem

---

But assuming this form is present when the page is rendered, I would just do this:

```
$("form").on('submit', function(e) {
    alert('You tried to submit the form');
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

(I'm assuming your page is rendered with the form already present)

Comment: It seems my problem lies with one of my form elements. I gave one an attribute of `name="disabled"` a perfectly legal name attribute as far as I can see? (I'm *not* trying to disable this field, simply give it a name value of `disabled`)

See an altered version of @Adam's code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/HtA58/) (original demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/xzeVX/)). As you can see, the form is submitted.

Is this a jQuery bug or is `name="disabled"` illegal?

Comment: @steveneaston - not sure if that's an invalid name or not.  That's a question for the html gurus :)  You may want to ask a new Q with `html` `dom` and `javascript` tagged.